# How can I convert a continuous raster into a discrete (categorical) raster using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, raster, classification

I am using QGIS 3.22.7, and I wish to classify a continuous raster with one band into 5 discrete categories based on raster values. The raster I am working with [can be found here (file size: 874 KB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19ovrmNKE6_aNQHGvco_jKHzJt44ACO-b/view?usp=sharing). (The projection is EPSG 6343). In ArcGIS Pro, this can be accomplished easily by selecting "symbology," choosing the "classify" option, and then selecting the number of categories you wish to classify the raster into. This changes it from a continuous to a discrete raster.

However, I am having difficulty doing this with QGIS. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QGIS has a Reclassify by Table tool as of QGIS 3.2.  [Here is a link to the tool documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/3.10/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/rasteranalysis.html#reclassify-by-table). This would result in a new raster layer split into your chosen categories.

If you want to only display in classes then open the layer's symbology.  Set to equal interval, define the number of classes you want.  Finally, click the values and type in values that you want.  [See this link for the official documentation on symbolizing by classes](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/training_manual/rasters/changing_symbology.html).

[image]

Comment: Plus you should set `Interpolation` to `Discrete` (not `Linear`, as in your screenshot).

Comment: Thank you very much!